# Prepared SQL Statement in PHP Not Updating MySQL Database Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, prepared-statement

I am attempting to update a MySQL database table with new rows from a PHP script. The script is called from a frontend HTML form that gets seralised and passed to the PHP as $_POST variables.

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE blog SET tag = ?, datestamp = ?, title = ?, content = ?, views = ?, shares = ? WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssiii", $tag, $datestamp, $title, $content, $views, $shares, $postid);
    $stmt->execute();

    / Check whether the execute() succeeded 
    if ($stmt->errno) {
        echo "FAILURE! " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else {
        echo var_dump($stmt);
        printf("%d Row updated.\n", $stmt->affected_rows); 
    }
```

The request does not throw am error, but the database row does not get updated, and it outputs "0 Rows updated". The serialised data is being sent as the right types (strings and ints where appropriate). Does anyone know what might be causing the issue?

echo var_dump($stmt) returns :

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(7) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Post an example of what the `echo var_dump($stmt);` will return.

Comment: Hi Racil, I've edited the post to clarify.

Comment: OK, what is the value of `$postid`? And can you confirm that this value exists in the database?

Comment: `/ Check whether the execute() succeeded ` is that a typo?

Comment: @JamesMilner are you sure that you're passing the right `id` parameter? Did you try running a `SELECT` statement with that `id`? I think that this value might not exist, that would explain the output you're receiving.

Comment: Issue was around attempting to do parsing on the incoming POST variables on the PHP script. i.e. parseInt($_POST["postid"] . Would be interested to know why this caused the variables to not be set.

Comment: Well, what was the value of `$_POST["postid"]`? If it does not start with a digit, the `parseInt()` function will return `NaN`. Also if it starts with zero, older JavaScript engines will use octal system, so `parseInt("010")` will return 8 instead of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, double check what is `$postid` and if that matches a record with id in blog table.

Also make sure you are using correct database (check the connection details).

**Side note:** do not use `echo var_dump()`, `var_dump()` itself will echo it.